# how populate select with json data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am practicing a shopping cart list but I cannot populate the select I have tried several times but without success. Any guidance would be appreciated.

**PHP:**

```
$get_cart =  mysqli_query($link,"SELECT cpro_id,cpro_name,cpro_price,cpro_qty FROM cart WHERE owner='$client'");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_cart)) {
$rows[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode(array("status"=>"OK","data"=>$rows));
return true;
```

**server response:**

```
{"status":"OK","data":[
{"cpro_id":"9","cpro_name":"Product1","cpro_price":"10.00","cpro_qty":"1"},
{"cpro_id":"10","cpro_name":"Product2","cpro_price":"10.00","cpro_qty":"1"},
{"cpro_id":"11","cpro_name":"Product3","cpro_price":"10.00","cpro_qty":"1"},
{"cpro_id":"12","cpro_name":"Product4","cpro_price":"10.00","cpro_qty":"1"},
{"cpro_id":"13","cpro_name":"Product5","cpro_price":"10.00","cpro_qty":"1"}
]}
```

**JS/HTML:**

```
<select name="info" size="1" id="info" style="display:block;width: 100%;">
  <option selected value="cpro_id">cpro_name</option>
</select>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: {
        action: 'getcart'
      },
      url: "api.php"
    })
    .done(function(cart) {
      //fill list
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: How is this question relevant to PHP? Also, when posting code, make sure it's properly formatted (like indent the code) or it's really hard to read it and follow the flow of the code. You should also include your attempt together with an explanation of the issue you're facing. We're glad to help you sort out issues with your code, but we're not here to just write it for you.

Comment: Are you having issues with the PHP code? If not, then there's no need to post it and that tag should still be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily `populate` your `json` data with `$.each` like below example:

```js
let obj = {
  "status": "OK",
  "data": [{
      "cpro_id": "9",
      "cpro_name": "Product1",
      "cpro_price": "10.00",
      "cpro_qty": "1"
    },
    {
      "cpro_id": "10",
      "cpro_name": "Product2",
      "cpro_price": "10.00",
      "cpro_qty": "1"
    },
    {
      "cpro_id": "11",
      "cpro_name": "Product3",
      "cpro_price": "10.00",
      "cpro_qty": "1"
    },
    {
      "cpro_id": "12",
      "cpro_name": "Product4",
      "cpro_price": "10.00",
      "cpro_qty": "1"
    },
    {
      "cpro_id": "13",
      "cpro_name": "Product5",
      "cpro_price": "10.00",
      "cpro_qty": "1"
    }
  ]
};

$.each(obj.data, function(i, v) {
  $('#info').append('<option value="' + v.cpro_id + '">' + v.cpro_name + '</option>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="info" size="1" id="info" style="display:block;width: 100%;">
  <option selected value="cpro_id">cpro_name</option>
</select>
```

In your code:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {
      action: 'getcart'
    },
    url: "api.php"
  })
  .done(function(cart) {
    $.each(cart.data, function(i, v) {
      $('#info').append('<option value="' + v.cpro_id + '">' + v.cpro_name + '</option>')
    });
});
```

Comment: thank so much! it works yay I need more practice with jquery :)

Comment: @Ajith They spend their reputation for fun :)